# Hotel Reservation System SQL query not returning output for date range for availability of room

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE AVAILABILITY 

AS
DECLARE @check_in AS DATETIME
DECLARE @check_out AS DATETIME


SELECT room_id,room_type 
FROM room
WHERE room_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT room_id 
    FROM   reservation B
           JOIN RoomReservation RB
               ON B.r_id = RB.r_id
    WHERE  (check_in <= @check_in AND check_out >= @check_in)
 )
 GO  
 Exec AVAILABILITY 




create table room(
room_id varchar(5) not null,
room_price varchar(7) not null,
room_type varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (room_type IN('Single', 'Deluxe', 'Superior')),
occupied  BIT DEFAULT 0 not null,
constraint Room_PK primary key(room_id)
)


create table reservation(
c_id varchar(5) ,
--room_id varchar(5) ,
r_id varchar(5) not null,
e_id varchar(5),
check_in date not null,
check_out date null,
constraint R_PK primary key(r_id),
constraint R_FK foreign key(c_id) references customer,
constraint R_FK1 foreign key(e_id) references employ,
--constraint RM_FK foreign key(room_id) references room
)



create table RoomReservation(
room_id varchar(5),
r_id varchar(5),
constraint RR_FK foreign key(room_id) references room,
constraint RoomR_FK1 foreign key(r_id) references reservation
)

insert into RoomReservation(r_id,room_id)
values --('T1','A1'),
--        ('T2','A2'),
--  ('T3','A3'),
--  ('T4','A4'),
--  ('T5','A3'),
 -- ('T6','B11'),
 -- ('T7','B12'),
 -- ('T8','A4'),
 -- ('T9','A5'),
 -- ('T10','A1'),
 -- ('T11','A7'),
 -- ('T12','C25')



insert into customer(c_id,phone,name,CNIC,m_id)
values--('C01','0418814342','saad','3330195894431','M01'),
  --('C02','0418814212','shahbaz','3330195894432','M02'),
  --('C03','0418814111','feroz','3330195894433',Null),
  --('C04','0418814222','serene','3330195894434','M03'),
         ('C05','0418814333','zoe','3330195894435',Null),
--  ('C06','0418814444','aslam','3330195894436',Null),
-- ('C07','0418814555','saleem','3330195894437','M04'),
--  ('C08','0418814666','zia','3330195894438',Null),
--  ('C09','0418814777','sami','3330195894439',Null),
  --('C10','0418814888','usman','3330195894430',Null)
select * from customer

insert into room(room_id,room_price,room_type,occupied)
values('A1','2000','deluxe',1),
('A2','2000','deluxe',1),
('A3','4000','superior',0),
('A4','5000','single',0),
('A5','2000','deluxe',1),
('A6','2000','deluxe',1),
('A7','4000','superior',0),
('A8','5000','single',0),
('A9','2000','deluxe',1),
('A10','4000','superior',0),
('B11','5000','single',0),
('B12','5000','single',0),
('B13','2000','deluxe',1),
('B14','4000','superior',0),
('B15','5000','single',0),
('B16','5000','single',0),
('B17','5000','single',0),
('B18','2000','deluxe',1),
('B19','2000','deluxe',1),
('B20','4000','superior',0),
('C21','4000','superior',0),
('C22','5000','single',0),
('C23','2000','deluxe',1),
('C24','4000','superior',0),
('C25','2000','deluxe',1)


select * from room

insert into reservation(c_id,r_id,e_id,check_in,check_out) 
values--('C01','T1','E0001','1-17-2015','1-18-2015'),
  --('C01','T3','E0001','2-2-2015','2-6-2015'),
  --('C02','T4','E0001','3-12-2015','3-15-2015'),
  ('C03','T5','E0002','3-12-2015','3-15-2015'),
  ('C03','T6','E0001','3-15-2015','3-17-2015'),
  ('C05','T7','E0003','3-17-2015','3-18-2015'),
  ('C06','T8','E0001','3-17-2015',Null),
  ('C07','T9','E0003','3-19-2015','3-20-2015'),
  ('C08','T10','E0001','4-12-2015','4-13-2015'),
  ('C09','T11','E0003','4-13-2015','4-14-2015'),
  ('C10','T12','E0001','4-14-2015','4-20-2015')
```

Instead it returns all the list of rooms in the hotel, not the available rooms within a specified date. I have tried several times to write a procedure or trigger to update occupied column of the room from 0 to 1, 1 to 0, but all my attempts failed.
EDIT:
Ok above has been resolved.
I have three entities,**ROOM**,**ROOMRESERVATION**,**RESERVATION**.
how to update status of the of occupied to 1 once a room has been reserved and to 0 once it no longer is reserved.

Comment: Maybe you should use the check_out parameter instead of using check_in twice.

Comment: I started to try to help with your problem, but your code does not run. Table creation scripts are missing, some parts of the sample data are commented out, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your query 
I hope you have to get  check_in date and check_out as parameters 
so query should be like beolow

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AVAILABILITY 
 @check_in AS DATETIME,
 @check_out AS DATETIME
AS

SELECT room_id,room_type 
FROM room
WHERE room_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT room_id 
    FROM   reservation B
           inner JOIN RoomReservation RB
               ON B.r_id = RB.r_id
    WHERE  (check_in <= @check_in AND check_out >= @check_in)
    )
    GO  

and you can call the procedure like 


exec AVAILABILITY '1-17-2015','1-18-2015'
```

Comment: still no luck.Even a simple code returns all the possible rooms in the hotel are returned

Comment: Your subquery is currently only going to get those rooms that are completely enclosed by an existing reservation. You probably want to account for all overlaps instead.

Comment: Can you help me with the occupied entity?I want to use a view or a trigger to update occupied once a room is reserved.?
I tried using an inner join and update reserved rooms to 1 but all rooms turned to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
SELECT room_id,room_type 
FROM room
WHERE room_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT room_id 
    FROM   reservation B
           JOIN RoomReservation RB
               ON B.r_id = RB.r_id
    WHERE  (check_out >= @check_in AND check_in <= @check_out)
    )
```

At least that's how I did it when I wrote a booking engine years ago.

Comment: Can you help with the occupied column?I cant seem to update it to 1,if update to 1 then cant change back to 0?

Comment: You haven't posted the code you are using to update the occupied column.   Add that code to your question and we can help to debug it.

Comment: SELECT RoomReservation.room_id,room.occupied
FROM RoomReservation
INNER JOIN room
  ON RoomReservation.room_id=room.room_id
  



UPDATE room SET occupied=1


select occupied
from room 
Inner join RoomReservation 
ON room.room_id=RoomReservation.room_id
INNER JOIN reservation
ON reservation.r_id=RoomReservation.room_id




SELECT reservation.checkout,room. FROM room
WHERE check_out is not null
UPDATE room SET occupied=0

Comment: could u write? where reservation.room_id=roomreservation.room_id

Comment: I can't, because I don't understand what you're trying to do with the update statements, or what it has to do with this answer or your original question.   Maybe it should be a new question.   What good is it to know if a room is occupied now, when someone is trying to make a reservation for next month?